# Why can java.util.zip.ZipException happen during Websphere deployment by jython script and wsadmin

Tags: java, unix, deployment, websphere, jython

I am trying to install myApp in Websphere 8.5 running over zOS/390. I can't imagine a more simple jython than below and it is returning "java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file". I am sure that the ear file is correct. Any idea about possible reason for ZipException will be appreciatted. Naturally, the server is up and running.

The Jython script:

```
000001,import sys
000002,EARFILE = "/usr/MyCompanyApps/MyArea/originEAR/MyAppEAR.ear"
000003,APPOPTS = "-appname "
000004,APPOPTS = APPOPTS + "dMYAPP "
000005,APPOPTS = APPOPTS + "-installed.ear.destination "
000006,APPOPTS = APPOPTS + "/WebSphereDevelopment/MYAPP/dtl/currr/deployment/ "
000007,APPOPTS = APPOPTS + "-MapModulesToServers [ "
000008,APPOPTS = APPOPTS + "MyApp MyApp.war,WEB-INF/web.xml WebSphere:"
000009,APPOPTS = APPOPTS + "cell=dtl85cel,node=wlemyAppa,server=WLEMYAPP] "
000010,AdminApp.install(EARFILE, APPOPTS)
```

The detailed trace log:

```
000064,java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Deploying /WebSp
000065," follows:
000066,
000067, com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException:
000068,,at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppManagementFactory.handle
000069,,at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppManagementFactory.readAr
000070,,at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppManagementFactory.readAr
000071,,at com.ibm.ws.scripting.AdminAppClient.getController(AdminAppClient.jav
000072,,at com.ibm.ws.scripting.AdminAppClient.commonPrepare(AdminAppClient.jav
000073,,at com.ibm.ws.scripting.AdminAppClient.doInstall(AdminAppClient.java:22
000074,,at com.ibm.ws.scripting.AdminAppClient.doInstall(AdminAppClient.java:20
000075,,at com.ibm.ws.scripting.AdminAppClient.install(AdminAppClient.java:1414
000076,,at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
000077,,at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl
000078,,at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcce
000079,,at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)

…

000125,Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Deploying /WebSphere/was85/dtl85c
000126,,at com.ibm.ws.sip.application.frameworkext.SarToEarConverterTask.isConv
000127,,at com.ibm.ws.sip.application.frameworkext.SarToEarConverterTask.execut
000128,,at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.processEar
000129,,at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.processEar
000130,,at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.getAppDepl
000131,,at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppManagementFactory.readAr
000132,,... 55 more
000133,Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
000134,,at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
000135,,at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:231)
000136,,at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:161)
000137,,at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:132)
000138,,at com.ibm.ws.sip.application.frameworkext.SarToEarConverterTask.isCon
000139,,... 60 more
000140,
000141,Ý11/9/15 11:14:24:931 CST¨ 00000001 AbstractShell E   WASX7120E: Diagno
000142,java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Deploying /WebS
000143," follows:
000144,
000145, com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException
```

I tried via Admin Console Wizzard and I got this message:

```
The following exception occurred. Check log for details. 
com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException: [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Deploying /WebSphere/was85/dtl85cel/ledm85nd/DeploymentManager/profiles/default/wstemp/867530631/upload/MyAppEAR.ear failed.]
```

Comment: do you have the proper permissions on the ear file you are trying to install?  Looks like the root cause is a perm error.

Comment: How could I check if permission is the issue? I went to the folder and I successfully created a directoy with "mkdir" and I successfully created a file with "oedit".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, thank you to all that try to help me here. I want to let here what has fixed my issue for future searchers: I am transfering the ear file from my windows machine to mainframe via Open Text FTP feature and, in my configurations, it was set up to Auto-Select. There are two file formats allowed: Binary and ASCII. Probably, autoselect was setting to ASCII. The correct is Binary.

Comment: I spent hours searching for this answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Few years back I remember we had this issue.
But at that time our /tmp filesystem was 98%, we cleared it and ran the job again it was successful.

Also other point is on permission,you can clear the wstemp & re-run.

Comment: Jagan, I set the permission to MyApp.ear with chmod 777. I set the permission to /tmp with chmod 777 and I checked that wstemp isn't full.I am completely stuck with "java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file". Such same message is happening when I try wsadmin>AdminApp.installInteractive('/WebSphereDevelopment/MYAPP/MyAppEAR.ear') as well.

Answer (score 1):

Oh ok.

Can you delete the contents of the wstemp and try to redeploy.

Wstemp folder contains Websphere temp workspace files.

Also to advise - can you try to deploy the EAR file manually via Admin console ?